# Changing AudioSource volume

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm trying to change my `AudioSource` `GameObject` volume and as the documentation says it's simply `myAudioSourceGameObject.volume = 0.5f`.

But, in my script I can't access any field called `volume`.

So how are you supposed to change your `AudioSource`'s volume through code?

Comment: when you write `myAudioSourceGameObject.volume = 0.5f` you get a compile error or you compile fine but nothing happens?

Comment: @user2320445 I don't even have the option to choose the `volume` field.

Comment: it is probably some Problem with the ide just write the code and compile it and see if it gives error

Comment: @user2320445 GameObject does not contain a definition for 'volume' and not extension method 'volume' accepting a first arguments of type 'GameObject' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)

Comment: @user2320445 I don't need to using some libraries for that statement?

Comment: it is not a gameObject it is an AudioSource

Comment: @user2320445 Ok. Changed it to and AudioSource but how you connect it to the unity Llike you do with GameObject.Find("MyGameObject")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it.

```
public GameObject go = GameObject.Find("MyGameObjectAudioSource");
void Update()
{
     go.GetComponent<AudioSource>().volume = 0.5f;
}
```

Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: Don't forget that you can accept your own answer - this way, it signals to others that the question has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

make an audiosource

```
AudioSource asour;
```

assign it , then change it

```
asour.volume = 0.5f;
```

Comment: Done that. but how you connect the Gameobject AudioSource from unity to your Script?

Comment: drag the audiosource iand drop it inspector

Comment: Done that also. But how the script knows which `AudioSource` am I using?

Comment: I just - GameObject- Audio - AudioSource - Attached the audio asset to the AudioSource AudioClip. How do the script know that im referring to this GameObject. it doesn't.

Comment: your script exposes a field in the inspector named asour grab the audiosource from the inspector and drop it into that field

Comment: can you take screenshots of what you did

Comment: I just - GameObject- Audio - AudioSource - Attached the audio asset to the AudioSource AudioClip in unity. Then in my script: `public AudioSource as;` Then in Update() - as.volume = 0.5f;  The GameObject is clearly not connected to the as reference. Do you understand?

Answer (score 0):

```
public gameobject MainCamera;

MainCamera.GetComponent<AudioSource>().volume = 0.7f;
```

Here MainCamera is referred as GameObject...

Answer (score 0):

```html
private IEnumerator ISetVolume(float Volume)
    {
        //Unity can't change volume of Audio Source Component instantly with no reason!
        yield return null;
        m_source.volume = Volume;
    }
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76205181/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).